# Loop through options in javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an javascript object that contains a select list. I'd like to loop through all options within the select. I'm trying the following:

`$(this+' .form-select option').each(function() {
      console.log(this);
    });`

A console.log of this shows that it contains the options but for *all* the option elements on the page not the options I've passed to it.

I get the following error "Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]"

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), like this:

```
$(this).find('option').each(function() { console.log(this); });
```

`this` is an object so you can't use it in a string, you can however use it to find other elements [relatively](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).  If `this` is already a jQuery object, just do:

```
this.find('option').each(function() { console.log(this); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `this` isn't a string with a selector in it, in which case your statement is invalid. My guess is your jQuery selector should be something like:

```
$('.form-select option', $(this)).each(function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? As long as the selector is valid, it would search for the selector in the scope of this...which seems to be what the OP wanted...